# Access the Gmail Api object in a cloud function in a Gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-functions, gmail, workspace

I followed that tutorial to create a Gmail Addon: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/quickstart/alternate-runtimes

I enabled the Gmail Api and would like to access the GmailApp class directly from my cloud function, but I can't really find information about how to do it, unless I create a new Google Script. Anyone knows if that is possible, I have a hard time finding useful documentation for addons.

When trying to use the GmailApp class, I get the error ReferenceError: GmailApp is not defined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.